# Stars(****) instead of actual password

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Im on a raspberry Pi project right now, and I stack somehow.

These are some parts of my code:

```
#some standard passwords
attempt = "0000"
passcode = "1234"    
haltcode = "4321"

#Getting the digits from the adafruit Keypad and store it to digit
while digit == None:
          digit = kp.getKey()

#Add each digit to attempt variable
attempt = (attempt[1:] + str(digit))  

#Clear and write on the LCD Screen
lcd.clear()
lcd.message("Password: " + attempt)

#Checking for the correct passwords
if (attempt == passcode):
    blah blah blah

if (attempt == haltcode):
    blah blah blah
```

I would like instead of the actual password, to print starts on the lcd scene. For example:

```
User enters 1-> Password: *
Then
User enters 2-> Password: **
Then
User enters 3-> Password: ***
Then
User enters 4-> Password: ****
```

Like the mobile phone when you enter your sims pin.
I don't know how this is possible. I would be more than grateful if you share with me some hints.
Thank you

Comment: don't print attempt then, just print a growing string of asterisks

Comment: `lcd.message("Password: " + "*"*len(attempt))`

Comment: Thanks cmd for your replay, your answer is smart but, the length of attempt is always 4. See first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is the line that does the printing (don't know, never worked with a RPi with peripherals before):

```
lcd.message("Password: " + attempt)
```

If that's the case:

```
lcd.message("Password: *")
```

Change the number of asterisks based on how many numbers have been entered so far